# how to return comma seperated values from within foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, foreach, linq-to-entities

This is what i am trying to achieve:

```
var result = (string)null;
foreach (var tagId in MultipleTags)
            { 
              result = string.Join(",", db.Tags.Where(t => t.TagId == tid).Select(e => e.TagName));
            }
```

This result variable should hold all the values in comma seperated form while MultipleTags contain sets of ids so it will iterate more than one time.

how should i write it. please suggest me.
I am doubtfull if this line is correctly written.

```
db.Tags.Where(t => t.TagId == tid).Select(e => e.TagName)
```

please suggest me something.

Comment: Assuming `Where(t => t.TagId == tid)` only returns one value (i.e. `TagId ` is the unoque key) then your code would only return one value (so there is nothing 'join')

Comment: i know thats why i have asked how to return back comma seperated values to this result variable because i have to select tagnames on the basis of tagId @StephenMuecke

Comment: You need a `.Contains()` to get all `Tags` matching `MultipleTags` - Fabio Luz's answer should so it.

Comment: So, `result +=`? Read [ask] and show example input and output, and what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
//assuming that MultipleTags is an array of "ids"
var result = db.Tags.Where(t => MultipleTags.Contains(t.TagId)).Select(e => e.TagName).ToList().Aggregate((a, b) => a + "," + b);
```

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Aggregate[String](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. this is what i am getting back and one more thing i am passing to controller IEnumerable<int> MultipleTags as parameter @Fabio Luz

Answer (score 0):

Try this too

```
var result = db.Tags.Where(t => MultipleTags.Contains(t.TagId)).ToList().ForEach((item) =>
            {
               item.TagName = item.id + "," + item.TagName;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
   var result = (string)null;
   result=string.Join(",", (from a in db.Tags join m in MultipleTags on a.TagId equals m select a.TagName));
```